# Error: Not a constant expression in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, assets, photo

I using the demo from this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view) and it works perfectly.
But when I implement in my project, I get error on this line

> Error: Not a constant expression. const
>   AssetImage(snapshot.data[index]),

My `Container` is wrapping in `InkWell`.

```
  InkWell(
      child: Container(
                 padding:
                      EdgeInsets.zero,
                     height: 150,
                      width: 150,
                      decoration:
                            BoxDecoration(
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                       image: AssetImage(snapshot.data[index]),
                                            fit: BoxFit .fill),
                                  ),
                           ),
      onTap: () {
               print('The value is ' + snapshot .data[index]);
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder:
                         (context) =>
                            const FullScreenWrapper(imageProvider:const AssetImage(snapshot.data[index]),  // here the error
                                    )));
               },
       ),
```

Here the printed value

> The value is
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xxx/files/Pictures/scaled_1572364487252xxx.jpg

If I remove the **const**, I get others error

> Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions. Try
>   making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the
>   constructor.

I even tried using `new` but to no avail.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Here `const AssetImage(snapshot.data[index])` you are using a `const` constructor. The compiler is expecting a compile time constant and is complaining because the arguments you are passing in are not constant but depend on the runtime value of `snapshot.data`.

If you simply remove the `const` keyword it should compile without errors.

Comment: Unfortunately I gives me anaother error `Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.
Try making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor.`

Comment: I guess you have to remove the `const` before the `FullScreenWrapper` as well.

Comment: I think I might have copied my code from somewhere and didn't realize it had a leading "const" keyword in front of one of my widgets. Removing it solved the problem.

Comment: accurate...
Thanks for this

Answer (score -9):

Make sure it has an internet device or simulator

Comment: erm..this doesn't make sense at all