# Dart: Access variable outside the function

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting error from compiler `Error: Not a constant expression. const AlertDialog(title: Text(application.title), content: Text("Test body"))),`

I have following code:

```
ListTile applicationListTile(Application application) {
  return ListTile(
    onTap: () => showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
          const AlertDialog(title: Text(application.title), content: Text("Test body"))),
    title: Text(application.title,
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        fontSize: 20,
      )),
    subtitle: Text(application.path),
    leading: Icon(
      Icons.javascript,
      color: Colors.blue[500]),
);
```

Is even it possible to access `application` variable from the function `applicationListTile` in the onTap builder callback? `application` variable is accessible in `title` property on the "first" level of the ListTile but not in the callback.

Comment: Remove the `const` before `AlertDialog`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Not a constant expression in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832925/error-not-a-constant-expression-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**const keyword can only annotate compile time constans**, not run time constants  . in your case `application.title` **(application object)** is a value that may change during run time (run time constant) can't be used with const. so, remove const before AlertDialog.

by the way, here is a shorthand comparison between compile and run time constants:

**compile time constant**: *predefined clear value that is known before program run*

**run time constant**: *value that is not known before run and must be calculated during the program run.*